# How can i remove an object from array of objects in app.delete using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i would like to remove an object of specified id:
I tried by this:

```
app.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const filtered = games.filter(function (el) {
      return el.id !== id;
    });

    res.send({ rest: filtered });
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

This although, does not remove the object in `games` array of objects, but returns the filtered array.  Does anyone have an idea on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter` does not change the original array, it creates a **new** array based on the filter you provided.

You could set the `games` array to the now filtered array, and that would remove the object.

```js
games = games.filter(function (el) {
  return el.id !== id;
});

res.send({ rest: games });
```